# Fetch Running Task by ID

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have created a function as follows

```
public int ManFunction()
{
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(RunTask, cts_token.Token);
    return task.Id;
}
```

Is there any way to get running task by task-Id in C#?

basically, when do I call function a second time I want to check whether the task is running or not? based on that I want to pass a notification to the user that the task is already running.

Comment: Could you include in the question the signature of the `RunTask` method? As a side note, you might find this interesting: [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/), and also this: [A Tour of Task, Part 9: Delegate Tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html)

Answer (score 4):

Using `Task.Id` to as identifiers bad idea. `Task.Id` is not unique [see remarks here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.id?view=net-5.0)

Your function instead of id can return `Task`:

```
public Task ManFunction()
{
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(RunTask, cts_token.Token);
    return task;
}
```

Basically you can work with `Task` object like with id, no difference to you. Than you can use `task.IsCompleted` to check is task done or not, like:

```
var t = this.ManFunction();
//.....
if (!t.IsCompleted)
{
    //.....
}
```